# has-one-through & has-many-through Laravel Eloquent Relationships

Tags: eloquent, relationship

```
Table 1 (Year)
Table 2 (Academic Year)
Table 3 (Admission Register

Table 1 field Names = id, title
Table 2 field Names = id, year_id
Table 3 field Names = id, batch_id, academic_year_id, roll_number,student_id,  admission_date
```

How to get year title from Table 1 through Table 2 (Academic Year) from Admission Register Model